# Can I apply a MessageHandler to certain attribute routes?

Tags: authorization, asp.net-web-api-routing, jwt

I know you can assign a handler using convention-based routing, e.g:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var tokenHandler = new TokenValidationHandler()
        {
            InnerHandler = new TokenValidationHandler()
            {
                InnerHandler = new HttpControllerDispatcher(config)
            }
        };

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "someApi",
            routeTemplate: "v1/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new object { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: null,
            handler: tokenHandler
            );
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this with attribute routing instead? What I'm trying to do is restrict some routes with a bearer token but allow other routes to allow anonymous access. Should I be using Filtering instead?

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested in this also, I want a global message handler that doesn't apply to certain request types or routes to a particular controller (similar to stonetip).

Currently I'm just bypassing all logic in my handler if the request is of that type or for that controller, however I don't think this is the most efficient method:

```
public class MyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (request.Method != HttpMethod.Get) 
        {
            System.Web.Http.Routing.IHttpRouteData routeInfo = request.GetRequestContext().RouteData;
            object objController = routeInfo.Values["controller"];
            if (objController == null || objController.ToString() != "excluded") 
            {
                //handler code for all non-excluded routes
```

Comment: I ended up going with a different approach since my specific need is to use JWT tokens to authorize certain routes. I found a neat solution using Owin. I'll be posting on my blog and linking from here as soon as I can even though it is not the answer to this question...might still be useful to someone.

Comment: I would love to see that solution :)